# MUI Pagination to Grid items

Tags: reactjs, pagination, material-ui, grid

I'm trying to paginate my grid in React App. I have Grid container, I have Object of objects, I render Grid items outta this object. And there're to many items on the page. Of course pagination is neccessary. But I have no idea how to implement it into responsive Grid system. I didn't find any documentation or tutorial about it. But I'm sure someone did it before.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if pagination is what you want since you seem to imply that all of your objects are loading on bootstrap. Pagination is usually handled via an API that will control objects that are returned. You probably need something like a  [Visibility Sensor](https://github.com/joshwnj/react-visibility-sensor)

Comment: See [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-volhard-i2le7) as well

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is what I looking for. The deal is that pagination, as well as Visibility sensor (as I understood) render somrthing depending on how many rows you want to show at a moment, or per page. And this number simply tracked by array.length. But... I don't actually render rows, I render cards, and the number of cards changes depending on screen size. I mean, any of online shops paginating theirs items, I just want do the same.